# SQL GROUP BY AND DOUBLE VALUE attributes

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database I have a table with fields Profit and Month, and Profit is type DOUBLE.

I am executing the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(profit ) AS profit , Month 
                    FROM general_Table
                    Where ID = '101' AND Year = '2017'
                    GROUP BY Month
```

I am sure that my database only contains doubles with two decimal points such as 9.02 or 3.79, but the result I get is

```
Profit             Month
904953.49          1
834431.1699999999  2
925363.4200000018  3
```

I expect that I shouldn't be getting more than two decimal points because only values that have two decimal points are entered. Could someone explain if my query is wrong?

Comment: You might want to read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html and **stop using FLOAT or DOUBLE to store exact scaled numerics like currency values.**

Comment: Also see [my 2013 tweet](https://twitter.com/billkarwin/status/347561901460447232): "If I had a dime for every time I've seen someone use FLOAT to store currency, I'd have $999.997634. #ieee754jokes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my database only contains doubles with two decimal points

The floating point numbers are approximations of real numbers. Most real numbers cannot be represented exactly using the floating point format.

Even using the usual numbers representation in base 10, most numbers cannot be represented exactly. For example, `1/3` is usually represented as `0.33` or `0.333` or `0.333333333333` but no matter how many `3` we put after the decimal point the value is not `1/3`. `1/3` cannot be represented exactly as floating point either.

Not all numbers that can be represented exactly in base `10` can be represented exactly as floating point; `0.2` is such a number.

"Two decimals digits" doesn't mean anything for the floating point format. It represents the values using binary representation, not decimal.

---

Back to your question, the most common (and probably the only) reason someone cares about the number of decimals of a number is when the number represents money.

Most RDBMS-es provide a data type that is designed to store amounts of money. They are implemented using fixed-point numbers and are exact.

On MySQL, use the [`DECIMAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html) type. The best thing you can do is to change the column type to `DECIMAL`:

```
ALTER TABLE general_Table
MODIFY COLUMN profit DECIMAL(9,2)
```

The declaration `DECIMAL(M,N)` stores the number on `M` digits that include `N` decimal digits and the integer part (`M-N` digits).

When it is used to store money, `N` is usually `2`. Adjust the value of `M` to match your needs. `DECIMAL(9,2)` allows exact representation of any amount of money from `-9,999,999.99` to `+9.999.999,99`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just two decimal points, then convert to decimal:

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(profit) as DECIMAL(9, 2)) AS profit , Month 
FROM general_Table
WHERE ID = 101 AND Year = 2017
GROUP BY Month;
```

If you are storing values using floating point representations, then the values are not exact -- as you note in your results.  It is recommended to store monetary values using fixed point representations (`decimal`/`numeric`).  Databases support two different ways of storing decimal values for a good reason -- some applications need exact precision, some need to be able to represent wide ranges of values.

For output purposes, you can convert to the fixed point repesentation.

Comment: Do we get the same result? i mean i think summing operator is doing miscalculations since the result has more decimal points than initial values at this point just casting the final value wouldnt help....

Comment: @ilkerKaya . . . You can do the cast before the sum, if you are concerned about that.  But you should really change the representation of the data to use `decimal`.  Don't fix the query, fix the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TRUNCATE` function for without rounding results and `ROUND` function for rounding results:

```
TRUNCATE(SUM(profit), 2)
```

Or:

```
ROUND(SUM(profit), 2)
```